# Editing phone videos with blender, audio is async?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I edited a video from my phone with Blender (changed colors + added text synced with the audio). But then I saw that later in the video, the text is not synced with the audio (for example a text comes from the top on a new beat)

Using ffmpeg I saw that the video has variable fps (which I think is normal for phone videos). Is there a solution where I can sync the text, or should I convert the video to constant fps with ffmpeg first? (I don't want to render twice, x1 with ffmpeg and x1 with blender which uses ffmpeg)

Answer (score 1):

Most NLEs needs footage which is not VFR, so you're right, you'll need to encode it to constant fps.

Velvet Revolver can be used to batch encode a folder to an intermediate files("lossless" with constant framerate): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tin2tin/blender_velvets/master/Blender_2.80/velvet_revolver.py

Info:
http://blendervelvets.org/en/velvet-revolver/

Comment: Will put forward Handbrake as another x-platform video converter to consider.

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of GUIs for ffmpeg: https://www.videohelp.com/software?toolsearch=ffmpeg&submit=Search&portable=&s=&orderby=Name&hits=50